# Check and retrieve if database column date is in the next X days

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a membership site where there is a specific expiration date for users. What I want to do is to get only users whom their membership will expire in X days and send them email.

There is a table in db called "mm_user_data", this is where the expiration date is stored in column named "expiration_date"

I can retrieve the expiration date of all users using this code

```
$sql = "SELECT expiration_date FROM mm_user_data";
$expire= $wpdb->get_results($sql);
echo var_dump($expire);
```

the output is this

```
[0]=> object(stdClass)#2455 (1) { ["expiration_date"]=> string(19) "2017-06-30 16:00:00" }
```

What I need to do is to check and retrieve column wp_user_id only if "2017-06-30 16:00:00" is in the next 10 days for example

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working

```
$daysPriorToRebill = 10;
$priorToRebillDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-{$daysPriorToRebill} days"));

$sql3 = "SELECT wp_user_id
FROM mm_user_data
WHERE expiration_date = '".$daysPriorToRebill."'";
$userid = $wpdb->get_results($sql3);
echo var_dump($userid);
```

Output  `array(0) { }`.

from this I want to be able to get user_email using `$userid` and then send him an email as renewal reminder. So my specific issue at the moment is getting the code above to work and retrieve users ids of users expiring in 10 days.

Comment: Hi. What is the output for `$sql3`  (or `$daysPriorToRebill`) ? The date is correct ?

Comment: The first one is correct, it outputs all dates, I want to only get dates that are in the next 10 days, SQL3 doesn't output anything, it's probably wrong

Comment: this is the output of $SQL

Comment: `string(79) "SELECT wp_user_id FROM mm_user_data WHERE expiration_date => '2017-01-04'" `

Comment: `=>` ? Should be `>=`, no ? Check if you have error with some tips as `($wpdb->last_error)`, see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141627/detecting-errors-generated-by-wpdb-get-results

Comment: Thanks @GeorgesO. , I found a solution, I posted it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do get IDs of all users that will expire in the next 10 days using this code

```
<?php
global $wpdb;


// This SQL retrieves all subscriptions That wil expire in 10 days

$daysPriorToRebill = 10;
$priorToRebillDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+{$daysPriorToRebill} days"));
$todaydate = date('Y-m-d');   

    $sql3 = "SELECT wp_user_id
    FROM mm_user_data
    WHERE expiration_date < '".$priorToRebillDate."' AND expiration_date > '".$todaydate."'";

$userid = $wpdb->get_results($sql3);


echo "<p>User ids are {var_dump($userid)}</p>";


?>
```

You'll notice I added  `AND expiration_date > '".$todaydate."'"` that is because it was retrieving all memberships that has an expiry date lower than `$priorToRebillDate` which 10 days ahead from current_day, so I needed to stop it from bringing anything that had already expired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql query to retrieve all users that have for example only 10 days left until their subscription ends using `DATE()`, `CURDATE()` and `DATEDIFF()`.

```
SELECT wp_user_id FROM mm_user_data WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE(expiration_date)) = 10
```

This query will return all userid-s of users whose subscription ends in 10 days. No need for painful date calculations with php.

Comment: I tested this, but it's not working for some reason, the output is 0 array, with PHP it outputs number if array that this condition applies to. It would be awesome if this can be done completely from mysql query

Comment: it is working for me me. check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e430b/1 . can you try with a sql management tool like mysql workbench or with phpmyadmin.  if same error please create a schema at sqlfiddle and send me the link